# Can I link to Business Objects universe in R?

Tags: r, business-objects

Is it possible to link to a Business Objects Universe in R?

I can connect R to a SQL database but that doesn't give me the Universe where all the joins are already created.  I have end users that currently get there data through Business Objects but R would better suit their needs.  And, since they are already familiar with field names and how the tables are linked in Business Objects, I would like for them to just link R to the existing BOBj universe.
Thanks!

Comment: This is surprising for new users, but asking for package recommendations is actually banned on StackOverflow (you can ask on Software Recommendations SE). So we should probably edit that out of your question.

Comment: Thanks @Hack-R.  That seems odd, it's not like I am paying someone for the package so it can't be banned for "advertising" reasons.  Either way, it is what it is and I appreciate you letting me know.  But the original question remains, is it possible to connect R to BOBj?  Thanks again.

Comment: Here's the text of the rule: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: @Hack-R thanks, makes sense.  So my question then goes to.  What has been done so far to solve the problem of connecting R to Business Objects?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not allowed to recommend specific software (new to me, but fair is fair :)) I'll just mention two options:
1) search the internet for software that gives odbc access to business objects universes. These are good keywords on my favorite search engine: 'odbc leverages SAP BusinessObjects Security'
It has the distinct advantage of making sure that all user access is being governed by business objects, but data will have to travel through that server, and you will need to pay for licenses to SAP as well as the vendor of the new odbc...
2) give the users in question ODBC access to the same tables that the BO reports/universe run against, and make sure they are allowed to see the SQL in their dataproviders. Then tell them to 'cook up a report, and the copy&paste the SQL to R'
Option two may save you some licenses and give you better performance, but I would personally go for option 1) :)

Comment: thanks for the information.  A quick search shows a 'bull' of a solution.  I will look into this more one I am finished with current projects.  This is still something I would like to achieve, I was just hoping for a magical R package that would work.  But, looks like the magic might need to be done outside of R.  Thanks again, and I will update if I find a solution.